# Creating precipitation raster map in GRASS GIS?

Tags: raster, grass-gis, interpolation

I am trying to create a potential erosion map of my basin for which I require a rainfall distribution map. I have 3 stations' rainfall data for the year 2007- 2015.

How do I create a rainfall map in GRASS GIS?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being an online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Answer (score 1):

The question can be separated in two parts:

1. What is a potential erosion map and how is it made based on rainfall station data?
2. How can I interpolate a surface based on 3 points using GRASS GIS?

For question 1,
I suspect you will need to get a yearly average per station (e.g. Station A: 900 mm/ year rainfall.  Station B:  150 mm/year rainfall.  Station C:  2200 mm/year rainfall).  Your case might be different depending on the method you are using - only you know this answer.  Once this is solved, you can go to question 2.

For question 2,
Google "GRASS Interpolation".  You will find tutorials in webpages and videos on YouTube.  Try them, and if you have specific questions after you have tried them, you can ask them here.

Comment: well, i have got yearly average per station in excel file. In which format do i have to arrange these data to import in grass gis?

Comment: do i have to make rainfall map for each year?

Answer (score 0):

See if the below link is any help.

http://fatra.cnr.ncsu.edu/temporal-grass-workshop/

Somewhere in there it tells you how to interpolate. You can try following the tutorial and later experiment with other options in interpolation.